# Syntax error on token 'else', { expected

Tags: java, string, if-statement, input, syntax

I am a bit new to Java and I tried to make this simple program of writing in the right string to make it print out "Password entered" and when something else was entered it would say "Wrong password". But it gave me this error which I had no clue on how to fix, it says ***Syntax error on token 'else',{ expected"***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String code = ("1908");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;

            System.out.println("Please enter password!");
        input = s.nextLine();

        if(input==code)
            System.out.println("Password entered!"); 
    } else { //<--- Syntax error on token 'else',{ expected
            System.out.println("Wrong password!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your indentation should be a big clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line `if(input==code)` you have forgotten to add the opening bracket so just add `{` to the end.

So will look like

```
if(input==code) {
    System.out.println("Password entered!"); 
} else { 
    System.out.println("Wrong password!");
}
```

**EDIT for comments**

The reason that `System.out.println("Password entered!");` is never printing is because you are using the `==` operator. When the `==` operator is used to compare objects it checks to see if the objects refer to the same place in the memory. Basically it checks that the objects names are referenced to the same memory location. An example of when you shouldn't use `==` would be like

```
// Create two Strings with the same text "abc"
String obj1 = new String("abc");
String obj2 = new String("abc");

// Compare the two Strings
if (obj1 == obj2) {
    // Will never reach here and print TRUE
    System.out.println("TRUE"); 
} else {
    // Will always print FALSE
    System.out.println("FALSE"); 
}
```

The above code will always print `FALSE` because the two String objects aren't located in the same place in memory - Confusing I know! To clarify when to use the `==` see the code below

```
// Create a new string object
String obj1 = new String("abc");
// Create another new string object but assign obj1 to it.
String obj2 = obj1; // obj1 and obj2 are now located in the same place in memory.

// Compare the two objects
if (obj1 == obj2) {
    // Will always print TRUE
    System.out.println("TRUE"); 
} else {
    // Will never print FALSE
    System.out.println("FALSE"); 
}
```

In he above code our two objects are located in the same place in memory so they are equal in the sense when it comes to comparison of the memory reference of each object.

But clearly you don't want to be comparing memory references of the objects you want to compare the String values that each object contains. So what you need to be looking at is the `equals()` method, I won't go into great detail about this but it basically compares two objects values and not the memory location. Have a look at the code below

```
// Create two Strings with the same text "abc"
String obj1 = new String("abc");
String obj2 = new String("abc");

// Compare the two String values using equals()
if (obj1.equals(obj2)) {
    // Will always print TRUE because the two string values
    // are equal/the same.
    System.out.println("TRUE"); 
} else {
    // Will never print FALSE
    System.out.println("FALSE"); 
}
```

So using what we have just learned about the `==` operator and the `equals()` method we can use this within your code so try changing to

```
// Using equals because you want to compare the String values
// not the reference to memory location for each object
if(input.equals(code)) {
    // Should print true if input value is equal to code value.
    System.out.println("Password entered!"); 
} else { 
    System.out.println("Wrong password!");
}
```

If you have anymore issues just leave a comment, hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks! Though I am having a problem after adding the {, it now doesn't print "Password entered!" anymore. Also, I changed } else { to } else if(!code.equals(input)) { to make sure it doesn't check for a specific string.

Comment: @FrederikLarsenBang I have edited my answer to include an explanation of why not to use `==` operator in your scenario and what to do instead. See section marked **EDIT for comments**

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use a `{` to open the 'true' clause in your if(), so when the `} else` is encountered, the `}` actually terminates the entire `if()`

It should be either of the following:

```
if (...) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}

if (...)
  ...
else {
  ...
}
```